# Why is the viewport meta tag not included in the standard?

Tags: html, viewport, meta-tags

Many sources stress the importance of including the viewport meta tag. As per [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) on MDN:

> Narrow screen devices (e.g. mobiles) render pages in a virtual window or viewport, which is usually wider than the screen, and then shrink the rendered result down so it can all be seen at once. Users can then pan and zoom to see different areas of the page. For example, if a mobile screen has a width of 640px, pages might be rendered with a virtual viewport of 980px, and then it will be shrunk down to fit into the 640px space.
>
> This is done because many pages are not mobile optimized, and break (or at least look bad) when rendered at a small viewport width. This virtual viewport is a way to make non-mobile-optimized sites in general look better on narrow screen devices.
>
> However, this mechanism is not so good for pages that are optimized for narrow screens using media queries — if the virtual viewport is 980px for example, media queries that kick in at 640px or 480px or less will never be used, limiting the effectiveness of such responsive design techniques.

And as per the [web.dev entry on viewport](https://web.dev/viewport/):

> Many search engines rank pages based on how mobile-friendly they are. Without a viewport meta tag, mobile devices render pages at typical desktop screen widths and then scale the pages down, making them difficult to read.
>
> Lighthouse doesn't check that width equals device-width. It also doesn't check for an initial-scale key-value pair. However, you still need to include both for your page to render correctly on mobile devices.

So, if I understand correctly, this tag is all but required: if not included, the page will be penalized by Google and mobile browsers will display the page incorrectly, ignoring media queries prepared especially for them.

Despite the above, according to the MDN page I linked to earlier, this tag "*is not part of any web standard*".

Why is that so?

WHATWG says in [their FAQ](https://whatwg.org/faq#living-standard):

> Instead of ignoring what the browsers do, we fix the standard to match what the browsers do.

Therefore, given that browsers make use of this tag and depend on it, wouldn't it be in accordance with the stated goals of the WHATWG to standardize this tag?

Perhaps something along the lines of:

> The use of the meta viewport tag means that the developer declares that their website is meant to be displayed also on devices whose screen size and/or resolution significantly differs from typical desktop sizes and resolution. Without it mobile browsers should assume that the page is not meant to be displayed on them and are free to apply heuristics that may break the developers' assumptions about how their site should work (for example, they may ignore media queries and render the page at artificially large widths only to downscale it just before displaying).

Why is the viewport meta tag not included in the HTML specs? Is there any rationale available?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a meta viewport tag. `viewport` is a setting of `name` which is an attribute of the `meta` tag.

`<meta>` is the tag, not viewport.

`name` then, [according to the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/dom.html#metadata-content-2), indicates

> Metadata content is content that sets up the presentation or behavior
> of the rest of the content

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, viewport is not a standard metadata name:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#standard-metadata-names

As far as I understand, the reason is that nobody has really pressed to make it a standard name (yet). Moreover, there is no pressure to make it a standard name since:

[next section: other names]
"Anyone can create and use their own extensions to the predefined set of metadata names. There is no requirement to register such extensions."

Would it be good if it was a standard name? Of course. It is annoying that something crucial like that is not a standard name.

But actually it is part of the html standard in a broader sense (other names of meta tags). I guess.